# AWS Identity federation clarification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

May I ask for some clarification on AWS IAM Identity federation for Mobile App scenario. After the App received temporary AWS credentials from STS, it uses those credentials(like Access key ID,a secret access key, and a session token) to access the AWS resource.
[AWS link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html)

Questions:
1. What happens in AWS after it received the credentials? it matches those credentials against which user? Does it creates a temporary user in the AWS account and sets the credentials for that user?
2. How the user data is preserved ? I mean if I created a Mobile Game App and want to store the player score, how the score data is preserved for days ?

Answer (score 0):

> What happens in AWS after it received the credentials?

Amazon verifies your credentials against the permissions assigned to those credentials. The API call that you are making is then authorized and is performed or is not authorized and the API fails.

> Does it creates a temporary user in the AWS account and sets the
>   credentials for that user?

No. A lookup is performed based upon the Access Key and validated with the Secret Access Key.

> How the user data is preserved ? I mean if I created a Mobile Game App
>   and want to store the player score, how the score data is preserved
>   for days ?

Amazon Cognito does support a limited amount of saved user data. This is stored in Key/Value pairs.

To add more functionality, use the Amazon Cognito Sync SDK.

[Amazon Cognito Sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/synchronizing-data.html)